# No implementation found for method camera animate on channel map recenter button

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

The Flutter map recenter button not working

dependency version = google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.6

Implement code

```
Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
LatLng lat = LatLng(ctrl.getLat().value, ctrl.getLang().value);
print(lat);
final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
controller.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
    CameraPosition(target: lat, zoom: 15.0)));
setState(() {});
```

}

```
E/flutter (15144): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method camera#animate on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_maps_0)
E/flutter (15144): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:165:7)
E/flutter (15144): <asynchronous suspension>
```

[image]

if anyone has a solution please drop a comment.

Comment: Did you try stopping the app and run again? some packages needs full stop and re running

Comment: tried but getting same error every time!

Comment: Lots of hits for that error message here and on the greater internet. Please [edit] this question and tell us research you have done, and why those other references may not apply (if they don't).

Comment: I have the same error. Its OK in the same app in other screen

Comment: @ManojJaiswaL did you find a solution for this?   what is the dependency version here?

Comment: @Kobi i have your same condition please tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 10):

```
  ///map controller
  Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController = Completer();

  ///create map controller
  void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    if(!mapController.isCompleted){
      mapController.complete(controller);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    mapController = Completer();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

here's works fine for me

Comment: This helped me solve my issue. To add context I had a map in showModalBottomSheet popup.

I received the following warning in debug:

Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed

The future had already completed in the code below when I tried to invoke the showModalBottomSheet  again:

final GoogleMapController animateController =
        await _controllerPopupMap.future;

So within my GoogleMap .whenComplete method, I had to re-initialize the Completer.

.whenComplete(() {
       _controllerPopupMap = Completer();
 });

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();


    if(!freezeMap) {
      _controller.future.then((value) =>

          value.animateCamera(
              CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(
                  LatLng(loc.lat, loc.long), zoomLevel)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependency version = google_maps_flutter:
```

Leave your dependency like this. Then save it if it's still not working
go through these steps:

In terminal:

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter run
```

Comment: how to check that the issue is resolved or not ?